# a c program to add two singly linked lists, of unequal lengths containing single digited numbers in all of their nodes

Tags: c, data-structures

i got this as an interview question. i was given 2 linked lists of unequal lengths,containing a single digited number in each of their nodes. i was asked to build a 3rd linked list which contains the sum of the two linked lists, again in the form of 1 digit in a node.
ex:
linked list 1 is
4-7-9-6
linked list 2 is
5-7
then the 3rd linked list would be
4-8-5-3
can someone suggest me an efficient algorithm, with minimum compromise in terms of space complexity?(i am not expecting an algo dat involves reversing the lists many times).

Comment: In what way is the sum of 4-7-9-6 and 5-7 equal to 4-8-5-3?

Comment: I have no idea. I was initially considering that it may be a case of aligning the ends of the lists and take sums mod 10, but then the result would've been 4-7-4-3.

Comment: I guess they're just integers, represented as lists of digits, so it's 4796 + 57 = 4853 ?

Comment: ya, paul. thats exactly what i meant. sorry about not being clear with that.

Comment: I hazard to guess that the correct answer to the interview question is "Is the list single or double linked?"

Comment: Since the OP mentions reversing the lists, I assume singly linked.

Comment: it would be very easy if it were a doubly linked list. its a singly linked list.

Comment: Maybe it was a good idea to ask "Why not keep them reversed all the time?"

Answer (score 3):

1. Reverse lists 1 and 2
2. Sum element-by-element (while
   maintaining a carry), putting the
   results in a list 3 that you
   construct from tail to head

OR

1. Convert lists 1 and 2 to ints (e.g. `int list1AsInt = 0; For each node {list1AsInt *= 10; list1AsInt += valueOfThisNode;}` )
2. Sum those ints
3. Convert the result to a linked list (e.g. `valueOfBrandNewNode = list3AsInt % 10; list3AsInt /= 10; Add a new node that points to the prev one;` )

OR

1. Traverse both lists once to find out
   their lengths.  For this example,
   let's assume that list 1 is longer
   by N nodes.
2. Create a list 3 to represent the sum
   without carries and a list 4 to
   represent the carries.
3. For the first N nodes of list 1,
   copy those values to list 3 and make
   list 4's values be 0.
4. For the remaining nodes of lists 1
   and 2, sum element-by-element,
   putting the sum mod 10 in list 3 and
   the carry in list 4.  Keep track via
   a bool of whether list 4 is all 0's.
5. Add a last node with value 0 to list
   4.
6. If list 4 is entirely 0's, done. 
   Else, recurse to step 2,
   treating list 3 as
   the new list 1 and list 4 as the new
   list 2.  We know the length of the
   new list 1 is the larger of the lengths
   of the old lists 1 and 2, and the length
   of the new list 2 is one more than that.

Comment: the 2nd soln wudnt work when the length of the lists is so long that the resulting integer cant be stored as an int.

Comment: and is there any other alternative to the 1st soln, where i dont have to reverse the lists?

Comment: I added a 3rd alternative that does not require reversing the lists, but its speed is very dependent on how many carries will be necessary.  Each carry can require up to 1 additional traversal of both lists.

Comment: +1 for good alternatives.  Re #1, worth noting that list reversal is possible in place.  Also, hybrids are possible: #2 as traversing but counting nodes, so on overflow can revert to #3.  Can also simply read nodes into std::vector<int8_t> then sum from the vectors.  Optimising #3: fixed-length window to speed carries, or save one/many/all node* N elements apart from before current node-summing point, to reduce rescans from head.  Or add ignoring carry (9+5=14) then move 2(+) pointers to consecutive nodes through a normalisation loop, carrying back a node at a time, until a loop finds no work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read each digit as its ASCII equivalent into a char array indexed from 0, for both lists.
2. Use the `atoi()` function on both char arrays ( you may use `atol()` or `atoll()` if you are concerned about the length)
3. Add both numbers
4. Use the `itoa()` function to convert to a char array & then put back into new list.

Although, I admit the `itoa()` function is not standard.

Comment: This would work only so long as your linked lists represented numbers that fit within the machine word. There's no reason there couldn't be a billion elements in a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are doubly linked it's easy:

1. Traverse both lists to the end.
2. Add the digits in corresponding nodes, and keep the carry digit.
3. Create the node in list 3.
4. Move one node towards the start of the lists and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be much simpler if the list stored the numbers in reverse order.

Nevertheless, with the given constraint, here is an approach.

1. find the [nthToLast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598348/) digit of both lists, starting with `n = 0`,
2. create a `node` with the sum of the digits,
3. update the (running) `carry`,
4. `insert` the newly created node at the `head of` the `result` list

Following is the (untested) C code.

```
typedef struct DigitNode_ {
    int digit;
    struct DigitNode_ * next;
} DigitNode;

/*  Returns the n-th element from the end of the SLL;
    if no such element exists, then return NULL.
    See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598348/
*/
extern DigitNode * nthNodeFromTail( DigitNode * listHead, size_t n );

/*  Push pNode in the front, i.e. as the new head of the list */
extern void pushFront( DigitNode ** pListHead, DigitNode * pNode );

/*  Create new list as sum of a and b, and return the head of the new list.
        a -> 4 -> 7 -> 9 -> 6 -> NULL
        b ->           5 -> 7 -> NULL
    results in
        c -> 4 -> 8 -> 5 -> 3 -> NULL
*/
DigitNode * sumDigitLists( DigitNode * a, DigitNode * b ) {

    DigitNode * c = 0;
    int carry = 0;

    /* i is the position of a node from the tail of the list, backwards */
    for( size_t i = 0; /* see 'break' inside */; i++ ) {

        const DigitNode * const ithNodeA = nthNodeFromTail( a, i );
        const DigitNode * const ithNodeB = nthNodeFromTail( b, i );

        /* Stop when processing of both lists are finished */
        if( !ithNodeA && !ithNodeB ) {
            break;
        }

        const int ithDigitA = ithNodeA ? ithNodeA->digit : 0;
        const int ithDigitB = ithNodeB ? ithNodeB->digit : 0;

        assert( (0 <= ithDigitA) && (ithDigitA <= 9) );
        assert( (0 <= ithDigitB) && (ithDigitB <= 9) );

        const int conceptualIthDigitC = carry + ithDigitA + ithDigitB;
        const int ithDigitC = conceptualIthDigitC % 10;
        carry = conceptualIthDigitC / 10;

        DigitNode ithNodeC = { ithDigitC, NULL };
        pushFront( &c, &ithNodeC ); 
    }

    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

```
node *add_two_linkedlist(node *head1,node *head2)
{
    int i,j,temp;
    node *p,*n;
    p=head1;
    n=head2;
    i=count(head1);
    j=count(head2);

    if(i>j)
    {
        while(j!=0)
        {
            p->data=p->data+n->data;
            if(p->data>10)
            {
                temp=(p->data)/10;
                p->data=(p->data)%10;
                p=p->next;
                n=n->next;
                p=p->data+temp;
                j--;
            }               
        }   
        return head1;
    }

    if(j>i)
    {
        while(i!=0)
        {
            n->data=p->data+n->data;
            if(n->data>10)
            {
                temp=(n->data)/10;
                n->data=(n->data)%10;
                n=n->next;
                p=p->next;
                n=n->data+temp;
                i--;
            }               
        }   
        return head2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward. Assuming the leftmost node is the most significant bit. Align the two lists, add and propagate carry. Upon return create a new node if required..

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct list {
 int val;
 struct list * next;
};


    int listadd (struct list  *l1, struct list *l2) {

        if ((l1 == NULL) || (l2 == NULL))
                return;
        int carry = 0;

        if ((l1->next == NULL) && (l2->next != NULL)) {
                carry += listadd (l1, l2->next) + l2->val;
                return carry;
        }

        else if ((l1->next != NULL) && (l2->next == NULL)) {
                carry +=listadd (l1->next, l2);
                l1->val = l1->val + carry;
        }
        else if ((l1->next != NULL) && (l2->next != NULL)) {
                carry += listadd (l1->next, l2->next);
        }
        else if ((l1->next == NULL) && (l2->next == NULL)) {
                l1->val = l1->val + l2->val;
                carry = l1->val/10;
                l1->val = l1->val%10;
                return carry;
        }

        carry = l1->val/10;
        l1->val = l1->val%10;
        return carry;
}

struct list * createnode (int val) {
  struct list * temp = (struct list *) malloc (sizeof(struct list));
  temp->val = val;
  temp->next = NULL;
  return temp;
}

int main() {
   int carry = 0;
   struct list *l1 = createnode(1);
l1->next = createnode(2);

   struct list *l2 = createnode(7);
   l2->next = createnode(8);

  carry = listadd(l1,l2);

  if (carry != 0) {
        struct list * temp = createnode(carry);
        temp->next = l1;
        l1 = temp;
  }


   while (l1!= NULL) {
        printf ("%d", l1->val);
        l1=l1->next;
   }
}
```