# Return the kth element from the tail (or end) of a singly linked list

Tags: algorithm, recursion, linked-list

[Interview Question]

Write a function that would return the 5th element from the tail (or end) of a singly linked list of integers, in one pass, and then provide a set of test cases against that function.

It is similar to question : [How to find nth element from the end of a singly linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598348/how-to-find-nth-element-from-the-end-of-a-singly-linked-list), but I have an additional requirement that we should traverse the linked list only once.

This is my solution:

```
struct Lnode  
{
    int val;
    Lnode* next;
    Lnode(int val, Lnode* next=NULL) : val(val), next(next) {}
};


Lnode* kthFromTail(Lnode* start, int k)
{
   static int count =0;
   if(!start)
        return NULL;

   Lnode* end = kthFromTail(start->next, k);
   if(count==k) end = start;
   count++;
   return end;
}
```

I'm traversing the linked list only once and using implicit recursion stack. Another way can be to have two pointers : fast and slow and the fast one being k pointers faster than the slow one.Which one seems to be better? I think the solution with two pointers will be complicated with many cases for ex: odd length list, even length list, k > length of list etc.This one employing recursion is clean and covers all such cases.

Comment: The two-pointer solution I'm thinking of is quite simple, and the only special case is if the length of the list is `< k`. That corresponds to your `if (count == k)` condition in a way.

Comment: @dacwe. How else do I keep a count of number of nodes traversed from the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2-pointer solution doesn't fit your requirements as it traverses the list twice.

Yours uses a lot more memory - O(n) to be exact. You're creating a recursion stack equal to the number of items in the list, which is far from ideal.

To find the kth from last item...

**A better (single-traversal) solution - [Circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer):**

Uses O(k) extra memory.

Have an array of length k.

For each element, insert at the next position into the array (with wrap-around).

At the end, just return the item at the next position in the array.

**2-pointer solution:**

Traverses the list twice, but uses only O(1) extra memory.

Start p<sub>1</sub> and p<sub>2</sub> at the beginning.

Increment p<sub>1</sub> k times.

while p<sub>1</sub> is not at the end
     increment p<sub>1</sub> and p<sub>2</sub>

p<sub>2</sub> points to the kth from last element.

Comment: Nice - like your circular array alternative.  (+1)

Comment: Really like your circular array based solution. This will be great if using extra memory is allowed.

Comment: @user1071840 Note that the recursive solution uses more memory than the circular array. Each recursive call (= number of items in list) uses more memory (because you need to store all local variables and a position in the function where to continue) than storing a single reference to an item in an array. So the array uses less memory overall (assuming k < number of items, can be made true when k > number of items by using a circular linked-list).

Answer (score 0):

```
'n' is user provided value. eg, 5 from last.

int gap=0 , len=0;
myNode *tempNode;

while (currNode is not NULL)
{
 currNode = currNode->next;
 gap = gap+1; 
 if(gap>=n)
   tempNode = currNode;
}
return tempNode;
```