# Finding element from last yielding object instead of value

Tags: python, algorithm, list, linked-list, nodes

I'm having a complex issue here with one of my questions for class, the question is:

> Find the element in a singly linked list that's m elements from the
>   end.

Following a few guides and reading questions on StackOverflow I was able to come up with the following code:

```
# Provided Node Class.
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

# Singly Linked List
class SinglyLinkedList:

    # Initiate current object as start of list.
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    # Add new node to list at currect position.
    def add(self, new_data):
        node = Node(new_data)
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node

    # Set head as starting point and walk through list.
    def Question5(self, index):
        walk = self.head
        while walk is not None:
            yield walk.data
            walk = walk.next

sll = SinglyLinkedList()
sll.add(1);
sll.add(4);
sll.add(3);
sll.add(8);
sll.add(1);
print ("Value at 4 is :", sll.Question5(4))
# ('Value at 4 is :', 1)
sll.add(0);
sll.add(0);
sll.add(0);
sll.add(0);
sll.add(0);
print ("Value at 0 is :", sll.Question5(0))
# ('Value at 0 is :', 0)
sll.add(22345643);
sll.add(12345643);
sll.add(14375643);
sll.add(12345633);
sll.add(12345647);
print ("Value at 12345643 is :", sll.Question5(12345643))
# ('Value at 12345643 is :', None)
```

However instead of my output being what I expect it to be my code shows this when ran:

```
('Value at 4 is :', <generator object Question5 at 0x7f9635bb3870>)
('Value at 0 is :', <generator object Question5 at 0x7f9635bb3870>)
('Value at 12345643 is :', <generator object Question5 at 0x7f9635bb3870>)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in this situation? Thank you.

Comment: Just read abut yield here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Comment: Ok I see, so perhaps using `yield` is not the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need yield in that case.

The algorithm you need depends on whether you know the size of the liked list or not.

### Size known

Given size of list `n`: Just return the `n-m`-th element of the list.

### Size unknown

#### Two iterations

The simplest trick would be to iterate over the whole list first, counting how many elements it contains. Then you know the size n and get the element as described above.

#### Remembering m elements

You can also solve this in one iteration if you 'remember' the last m elements you've seen in the list. Then iterate until the end of the list and return the 'oldest' element you still remember.

#### Using two pointers

This last approach uses two pointers to two elements of the list that always have a distance of m elements. They are both moved simultaneously. If the first pointer reaches the end of the list, the second pointer exactly points to the element m elements from the end of the list.

See [How to find nth element from the end of a singly linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598348/how-to-find-nth-element-from-the-end-of-a-singly-linked-list) for details. The code in that post is C++, but it shouldn't be too hard to understand.